# Memory leak caused by img.setBackgroundResource

Tags: java, android, animation, garbage-collection, android-animation

I have an animation I want to run, and when I set the drawable for it, there is a memory leak. I dont know if it matters, but the frames are only in the drawable folder and not in specific dpi folders. The memory leak happens even before I start the animation. It happens when I set the resource of the animation.
Thanks!

The call:

```
logoAnimation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.logo_animation);
```

logo_animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo0" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo1" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo2" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo3" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo4" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo5" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo6" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo7" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo8" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo9" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo10" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo11" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo12" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo13" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo14" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo15" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo16" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo17" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo18" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo19" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo20" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo21" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo22" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo23" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo24" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo25" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo26" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo27" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo28" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo29" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo30" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo31" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo32" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo33" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo34" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo35" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo36" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo37" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo38" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo39" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo40" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo41" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo42" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo43" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo44" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo45" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo46" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo47" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo48" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo49" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo50" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo51" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo52" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo53" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo54" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo55" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo56" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo57" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo58" android:duration="35" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo59" android:duration="35" />

</animation-list>
```

Logcat output:

```
08-08 12:42:10.710: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 3% free 10269K/10567K, paused 2ms+1ms
08-08 12:42:13.135: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 115K, 3% free 10490K/10759K, paused 10ms
08-08 12:42:13.160: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 130K, 4% free 10781K/11143K, paused 9ms
08-08 12:42:13.215: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 195K, 4% free 11155K/11527K, paused 25ms
08-08 12:42:13.265: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 130K, 4% free 11512K/11911K, paused 20ms
08-08 12:42:13.295: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 195K, 4% free 11951K/12423K, paused 10ms
08-08 12:42:13.325: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 260K, 4% free 12535K/12999K, paused 9ms
08-08 12:42:13.360: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 325K, 4% free 13266K/13767K, paused 9ms
08-08 12:42:13.400: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 391K, 4% free 14143K/14727K, paused 9ms
08-08 12:42:13.450: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 521K, 5% free 15313K/16071K, paused 10ms
08-08 12:42:13.510: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 587K, 5% free 16628K/17415K, paused 10ms
08-08 12:42:13.570: D/dalvikvm(6122): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 587K, 5% free 17942K/18759K, paused 10ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading quite a large number of images, around 60. If these images are also relatively large, this makes me think that the memory leak is caused by the `OutOfMemoryException.`

[Here's a great article](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on how to deal with it.
In short, the idea is that you should scale down your images before loading them in memory.

Comment: The images are 512x512 each. But if I make them smaller it will be quite small. It should be a loading logo. And what if I just leave it this way? Can it cause issues after the exception is thrown?

Comment: Well, you could catch the exception at least. What will follow after this, you can test and see it yourself. But maybe you should re-think the animation logic. For example to do it programatically and load one image at a time, as soon as the image passed away, free the memory.

Comment: One idea is to have a canvas that redraws itself every 35 milliseconds (your delay) with a new image. Here is a some more code to write, begin by investigating various way of animation, and how to free memory allocated.